# How to validate object in pydantic only after creation

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic base model that I'd like to be able to be constructed by both dict and obj

And I have 2 validations. One of which I want to be used only after it is constructed as an object

```py
class A(BaseModel):
    name: str
    color: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def validation_a(cls, fields):
        pass

    @root_validator
    def validation_b(cls, fields):
        pass
```

I'd like `validation_b` to be only after it is obj (not on the dict before

For now everything I tried did the validation beforehand